# extract data between single quotes

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-re

trying to extract the data between single quotes

```
import re 

a = 'USA-APA HA-WBS-10.152.08.0/24'

print(re.findall(r'()', a))
```

expecting the oputput : USA-APA HA-WBS-10.152.08.0/24

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: USA-APA HA-WBS-10.152.08.0/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with python but with some quick searching around
I've found that this work

```
import re

a = 'USA-APA HA-WBS-10.152.08.0/24'
result = re.findall(r'(.*?)', a)
print("".join(result))
```

I'm pretty sure there are better ways of solving this but I'm not familiar with the language

Comment: ... or just `print(a)`

Comment: Yes as I said I'm unfamiliar with python and the case aswell. 
Maybe he wanted to find in a big text with double quotes all the texts with single quotes. I dunno :(

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with ?  It is just a string ?

```
a = 'USA-APA HA-WBS-10.152.08.0/24'
print(a)
```

Output:

```
%  python3 test.py
USA-APA HA-WBS-10.152.08.0/24
```

You might want to look at this also regarding quotes and strings:

[Single and Double Quotes | Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/single-and-double-quotes-python/)